# Magento 2 Custom Customer Attribute Save Data and edit data, i have problem

Tags: module, customer, configuration, magento2-migration-tool, mapping

I create a customer module this module working good , when I migrate data  mangento 1.x to magento 2.x wiht migration tool and i wish crete a new customer don’t save data or edit any customer don’t show data

[image]